# MySQL Connection refused when running multiple processes

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

We are running multiple scripts that calculates data. The script was written in PHP(Laravel) and they were triggered by a cron(every minute). What I have noticed is when the cron triggers more than 300 of those process, mysql crashes "Connection Refused". This issue doesn't happen when there are less than 300 processes. I already have increased max_connections to 1000 and back_log t0 500 in my.cnf but the issue still persists(of course MySQL service was restarted). I have seen someone say that back_log is also at OS level but I can't find any article on how to adjust it. Any thoughts?

Here's some config values:

```
max_connections         = 1000
back_log                = 500
connect_timeout         = 5
wait_timeout            = 600
max_allowed_packet      = 64M
thread_cache_size       = 256
sort_buffer_size        = 128M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 128M
tmp_table_size          = 128M
max_heap_table_size     = 1G

myisam_recover_options = BACKUP
key_buffer_size         = 128M
#open-files-limit       = 2000
table_open_cache        = 400
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 512M
concurrent_insert       = 2
read_buffer_size        = 8M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 4M

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 80G
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 256M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_open_files       = 400
innodb_io_capacity      = 400
innodb_flush_method     = O_DIRECT
```

Comment: this question is very broad, and debatable, no specific answer can be given... for example, why is buffer_pool_size = 80G when concurrent_insert is just 2? if you take a forensic view both are contradictory for a specific machine

Comment: enable slow query log, set long_query_time low(er than the default of 10 seconds). `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}`, `EXPLAIN {query}` information needed too.

Comment: concurrent_connection can only accept 0, 1 or 2 values where 2 means Always so I don't think it is related with the innodb_buffer_pool_size?

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be a performance issue, Did you monitor the mysql server cpu usage?

Comment: CPU usage is less than 10% and Memory is less than 50%